# Testing FPU on arm processor

Tags: gcc, floating-point, arm, fpu

I am using a Wandboard-Quad that contains an i.MX6 ARM processor.  This processor has an FPU that I would like to utilize.  Before I do, I want to test how much improvement I will get.  I have a benchmark algorithm and have tried it with no optimization, and with -mfpu=vfp and there appears to be no improvement -- I do get improvement with optimization = 3.

I am using arm-linux-gnueabi libraries -- Any thoughts on what is incorrect and how I can tell if I am using the FPU?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: May be it assumes vfp support by default. Check toolchain build options, `gcc -v`. Stuff written about optimization is also true, but it might be just that your benchmark is poor.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the assembler output with a -S flag and see if there are any fpu instructions being generated.  That's probably the easiest thing.

Beyond that, there is a chance that your algorithm was using floating point so rarely that any use would be masked by loading and unloading the FPU registers.  In that case, O3 optimizations in your other parts of the code would show you gains separate of the FPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

`-mfpu` option works only when GCC is performing vectorization. Vectorization itself requires reasonable optimization level (minimum is `-O2` with `-ftree-vectorize` option on). So try `-O3 -ftree-vectorize -mfpu=vfp` to utilize FPU and measure difference against simple `-O3` level.

Also see [ARM GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) for cases where `-funsafe-math-optimizations` may be required.

Answer (score 0):

Without any optimisation the output from GCC is so inefficient that you might actually not be able to measure the difference between software and hardware floating point.

To see the benefits that the FPU adds, you need to test with a consistent optimisation level, and then use either `-msoft-float` or `-mhard-float`.

This will force the compiler to link against different libraries and make function calls for the floating-point operations rather than using native instructions.  It is still possible that the underlying library uses hardware floating point, but I wouldn't worry about that too much.

You can select different sets of FP instructions using `-mfpu=`.  For i.MX6 I think you want `-mfpu=neon`, as that should enable all applicable floating-point instructions (not just the NEON ones).